# segue if cant access all of them

Tags: swift, if-statement, segue

Hello i have problem because i have a var count that is += 1 when i press a button so, when i update de counter it doesnt function all the segues. for example if the count == 2, i want to acces count == 1 and count == 2

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "modos" {
        if count == 1 {
           if let destination = segue.destination as? ModosViewController {
               destination.nnj1 = nombresJugadores[1]
           }
        }
        if count == 2 {
           if let destination = segue.destination as? ModosViewController {
               destination.nnj2 = nombresJugadores[2]
            }
        }
```

Comment: But then why are you incrementing `count` if you are going to use the contents of both if-statements anyway?

Comment: The purpose of having two if-statements would be to preclude one set of instructions based on the value of the `count` variable.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry because it depends off the numbers of names that the user introduces

Comment: That's really vague, can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you really want to happen on the screen for each of the two cases?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry i have a button that every time you press it, adds a name on a textfield to an array and the count += 1 every time its pressed, so i need the counter to access array elements so if there only 1 name i cant put 2 segues because it will crash because i only have 1 name, thats why i need the counter

Comment: @PhillipMills i want to pass the data off the segue but if i dont know how many names i will have

Comment: Are you doing this so that an infinite amount of names could be added, or just two?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry infinite amount of names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want to be able to pass as many names as you want to your destination controller, your current approach won't work.

You need to have an array in your destination view controller that new names can be appended to. This way you can just call the index of each item in your destination controller. With your approach, you would have to create an infinite amount of `nnj` variables, which obviously isn't feasible.

So this would look something like this:

```
class ModosViewController: UIViewController {
    var names: [String] = [String]()
    ...

}
```

Then what you can do is just change the `prepareForSegue` func to this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "modos" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ModosViewController {
            destination.names = nombresJugadores
        }
    }
}
```

Because now you have an array of names in your origin that you pass onto the destination VC. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much, thats what i needed! very very helpful